# Some posts to a question were delayed being shown?

Tags: support, answers, merged-questions

About an hour ago I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214178/mysql-optimization-current-previous-orders-should-be-on-different-tables-or-s/4214375#4214375).  When I viewed the question there were no answers.  About thirty minutes later, I viewed the question again and saw that this time there was an answer that had been accepted.  And that answer had been posted 4 hours ago.  And there was a comment by the OP thanking him for his answer, 30 minutes before I had posted mine.  There wasn't a whole lot of time either between when I viewed the post and when I posted an answer, no more than 10 or 15 minutes.  I deleted my answer because it didn't really add to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the answer, but I didn't [check the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4214178/revisions)!

You're right, there was no answer on the question when you answered it. That's because you were [answering a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214186/mysql-optimization-current-previous-orders-should-be-on-different-tables-or-s). The merge happened shortly after you posted your answer.

I'm concluding that your answer was on the merge-from question, as the other answer doesn't have merge history in it and you have a revision on the other question. My guess is, when you went to re-look at the question, you did it by visiting your answer. That now directs to the merge-to question, so it looks very awkward indeed.

Comment: The timestamp of my answer was 15:16:16.  I couldn't have viewed the question until after 14:00:00, as that was the time I showed up at the office to use the computer I viewed it with.

Comment: @YWE That is very curious, then. Stack Overflow doesn't implement a blocking system (it's been declined several times in the past), so I can't even guess what would cause it. I'm not even sure how one might try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Grace: Check this out and tell me if you see that I deleted and undeleted the post: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4173716/revisions

Comment: @Jon Aye, I do see it. That was also [the first thing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4214375/revisions) I checked on the answer, it wasn't deleted/undeleted.

Comment: @Grace: Yeah. I wasn't sure if other users could see the delete/undelete events. Thanks.

Comment: There you go. Nice find. +1

Comment: Thanks.  I had no idea about merges.